# Python, "вычитаение" списков с сохранением последовательности

Tags: python, list

есть:

```
a = [5, 2]
b = [5, 2, 7, 8]
```

нужно "вычесть" a из b и получить [7, 8]

Comment: Какой ожидается результат для `a = [2, 2]` и `b = [2, 2, 2]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = [5, 2]
b = [5, 2, 7, 8]

set_a = set(a)
c = [v for v in b if v not in set_a]

print(c)
```

Comment: А зачем вы преобразуете a в множество? Так будет быстрей производится поиск?

Comment: Так тогда зачем?...

Comment: Без `set_a` сложность алгоритма `len(b) * len(a)`. С `set_a` сложность алгоритма `len(a) + len(b)`. Попробуйте `a = list(range(1000000))`, `b = list(range(1000002))`.

Comment: @Глеб, да, Stanislav прав, я не учёл, что "первое вхождение" в списке с большим числом копий может быть очень далеко.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте это:

```
[entry for entry in b if entry not in a]
```

Comment: Неплохой вариант. Только не пойму, почему у вас в `entry`, а не классические `i` или `c`?

Comment: `i` обычно используют как `i`ндекс, исторически используют `i`, `j`, `k`. Почему я должен использовать `c`? В `c` я поместил бы результирующий список. На мой скромный взгляд, `entry` или `item` - наиболее идиоматичны, но вы вольны использовать любой допустимый идентификатор и на алгоритм это не повлияет.

Comment: Просто я почти никогда не видел, чтобы в списковых включениях использовалась многострочная переменная. А вот как используют в нем `c` и `i` асы с Codewars видел неоднократно.

Comment: Ну, иногда еще используют x, y и n.

Comment: @Глеб, это дело вкуса, привычки, культуры кода и принятым стандартам в команде. Мы вот пишем так и нам нравится. Кроме того, я нигде не использую однобуквенные идентификаторы, кроме примеров и устоявшихся конструкций, а также устоявшихся имён, таких как `x` или `y`.

Comment: Верно. `if entry not in a`, так нужно.

Comment: И кстати, как раз-таки устоявшиеся имена x y употреблять по стандартам не рекомендуется, потому что быстро забудешь что они означают.

Comment: @Глеб можно забыть, что `x` - это координата икс?

Comment: Это единственное исключение. Во всех остальных случаях полагается использовать осмысленные переменные (как у вас в списковых включениях, только на месте)

Comment: @Глеб в других случаях я его и не использую. А, ещё чтобы обозначить неизвестное в уравнении.